# Installed applications are not working or unable to uninstall

Tags: 20.04, snap

I have few applications which were working properly, suddenly those applications logos are missing only name shown in the application list. When I click those applications it shows like opening but not. So, I tried to uninstall but it failed with the result

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge sublime-text
[sudo] password for yasithan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "sublime-text", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install sublime-text"

E: Unable to locate package sublime-text
```

But when i try to install it

```
snap install sublime-text
snap "sublime-text" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

Please help me with this issue.
And please let me know if any feather details required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi K. Yasithan! Besides Sublime Text what are the other affected apps? (Are they all snaps?) What happens when you try to open sublime text from the terminal? Type `subl` to try.

Comment: what does "snap list" say ?

Comment: maybe remove the sublime-text snap and reinstall it : sudo snap remove sublime-text & sudo snap install sublime-text

Comment: Other affected apps are opera browser, zoom application.
@Koen's answer helped me to resolve it.
thank you very much for your effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snap & apt are different tools

apt manages packages (debian-type packages as ubuntu uses)

snap allows to install software in another way

some software is available in both formats and then you should use one or the other

to remove a snap : `sudo snap remove`

to install a snap : `sudo snap install`

some snaps require the --classic option when installing : `sudo snap install sublime-text --classic`

list installed snaps : `sudo snap list`

Comment: Thank you very much Koen, this helped me.